# Is Certificate Name Filtering possible with Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, x509, client-certificates, distinguishedname

I know it is possible with APACHE using SSLRequire ( %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Foo Net" and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU } in {"Department of Department Creation"} )

Is there any similar capability with Glassfish ?

Thanks,
Dave